# Postfix- call web service after receive of mail

Tags: ubuntu, postfix

I have postfix installed in ubuntu.
I want **postfix/any other way(please suggest)** to call the web service and provide the email in text format to that.

FYI: the web service contains the code to read the keywords in email and reply to that mail accordingly(so the headers must also be sent to the webservice)

what can i do? please help

Comment: Sounds like this would be something the providers of said webpage could provide you with.

Comment: whenever i get a mail, that mail's body and a sender id must be sent as a parameters in the http request.
for ex: I want postfix/something to call http://example.org/xyz.aspx?body=mail-content&id=sender@pqr.com
So the mail body and sender id must be inserted whenver the mail comes.
These are my requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BTW: I got the answer for FREE

we can use shell script as in [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1229870)

or php as in [here](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/security-admin/parsing-e-mails-via-postfix-and-php/)

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to write something you can use as a postfix transport, which then calls the webservice for you. It'll need to read in the email on stdin, do the relevant http request and exit with an appropriate exitcode (0 for success, 66 for temporary failure etc.). See also the [manpage for transport](http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html).

Comment: hey, can you help me what is that something i can write? The link did not help me much... 
can we make it like postfix calling a script and script doing the rest of the work? can i do like this? how exaclty?

Comment: I can send you my hourly consulting rates if you like, but this is not a "get someone to write me something for free site" I'm afraid.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this forum